# LibreOffice issue: some packages are listed as removed

Tags: package-management, software-installation, libreoffice, debian

```
dpkg -l | grep -i libreoffice
rc  libreoffice-calc                     1:4.3.3-2+deb8u12                 amd64        office productivity suite -- spreadsheet
ii  libreoffice-common                   1:5.2.7-1+deb9u11                 all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent files
rc  libreoffice-core                     1:4.3.3-2+deb8u12                 amd64        office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
ii  libreoffice-java-common              1:5.2.7-1+deb9u11                 all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent Java support files
ii  libreoffice-style-galaxy             1:5.2.7-1+deb9u11                 all          office productivity suite -- Galaxy (Default) symbol style
rc  libreoffice-writer                   1:4.3.3-2+deb8u12                 amd64        office productivity suite -- word processor
ii  uno-libs3                            5.2.7-1+deb9u11                   amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment -- public shared libraries
ii  ure                                  5.2.7-1+deb9u11                   amd64        LibreOffice UNO runtime environment
```

libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-core and libreoffice-writer pkg are listed in the results of `dpkg -l | grep -i libreoffice` as removed. How can I install these packages?

Answer (score 4):

Three packages are listed in the results of `dpkg -l | grep -i libreoffice` with `rc` flags meaning that these packages have been removed, but their configuration files have not been deleted. To install these removed packages open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-writer # remove old config files 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-writer
```

Answer (score 2):

@karel gave a good link, which is https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages

I'll write out what it says, just in case the page is removed later.

Try reinstalling the package with `aptitude` instead of `apt install`

You can try:

`sudo aptitude install <packagename>`

or:

`sudo aptitude -f install <packagename>`

`aptitude` in general will give up less easily. The difference between these commands is that `-f` will mean that `aptitude` will attempt to remove/downgrade less packages, even if it means not all changes will go ahead.

Edit: I'll add another solution, just in case this doesn't work.

Try `sudo apt update` OR try `sudo apt autoremove`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for providing the attribution.

Comment: No problem. People deserve to be appreciated when they contribute something good.